# Creating widget using javascript and PHP

Tags: php, javascript

I am working on creating widget using PHP and Javascript. In a widget, you get a small code like this:

```
<div id="wd_id"></div><script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/hasanResearch/php/widgets/widget.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">init_widget()</script>
```

You need to paste this code in your html file. This piece of code calls a function **init_widget()** in **widget.js**. The script inside `widget.js` is somethis like this:

```
function init_widget(params){
    document.getElementById("wd_id").innerHTML='html code goes here';
}
```

This will load the entire html page. In my case, the JS file and all the files are located on server. I have copied the code in my local. When I open the html file in browser, it shows error as `Uncaught ReferenceError: init_widget is not defined`.

Do anyone have clue, why it is happening?

Comment: should `http://localhost/hasanResearch/php/widgets/widet.js` be `http://localhost/hasanResearch/php/widgets/widget.js`

Comment: sorry, my mistake. I have entered wrong filename is question. I have updated the question.

Comment: check in firebug whether this file is actually getting loaded.
http://localhost/hasanResearch/php/widgets/widget.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/hasanResearch/php/widgets/widget.js"></script>
```

Instead of refering actual `url src="http://localhost/hasanResearch/php/widgets/widget.js"`
Refere with your base url

Like `src= "/hasanResearch/php/widgets/widget.js"`

Answer (score 1):

your script tag is calling "widet.js" not "widget.js".